# Maven building - Main Class not found

Tags: java, maven, build

I have some  problems with maven. It used to work just fine until a few minutes ago...

This is what i get whenever i try to build now:

---

### T E S T S

Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ImageMagick;C:\Program

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

pom.xml files are okay...Everything worked and now i cant get it to build anymore. Tried reinstalling java, maven, everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in a path that isn't wrapped with quotes.

Does the following look correct?

```
C:\Program
```

No it isn't, it indicates that you are on a Windows machine and the path is being split on a space, you need to wrap them in <kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: Yes i have spaces in PATH variable where the path is C:\Program Files\something

Comment: But how to fix that. It used to work just fine until now